# css floating element increase parent height but sibling with 100% height not working

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 2 children : one is floating and increasing his parent's height, the second is not floating and fill the rest of the width. I'd like to make the second filling the height also.

Here is a fiddle of my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/LAesa/

In this fiddle I'd like to make the red div filling 100% height of his parent.

Here the html :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="float">
        The floating <br/>column
    </div>

    <div id="fill">
        This one fill the rest
    </div>

    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
```

Here the css :

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: yellow; 
}

#float {
    width: 20%; 
    float: left; 
    background-color: green; 
}

#fill {
    min-height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: red; 
}

.clearfloat {
    clear: both; 
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Nope, it depends on his content

Comment: What happens if the floated green section is shorter than the in-flow red block?

Comment: It would be ok but I can't be sure that my red block is bigger.

Comment: How about legacy browsers? IE7?

Comment: There is a posted solution using table cells, is that good for you?

Comment: I was going to propose a solution using `display: table-cell` which some people like and others don't.  Before spending time on it, I decided to ask, but by that time, someone else posted a solution and you accepted it, so no need for me to do anything!

Comment: Thank you anyway :) I'm not really in love with tables solution but in this case it looks perfect so I'll keep it hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you don't need to support older browsers you can also use the flexbox layout.  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ http://caniuse.com/flexbox

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div id="left">
        The floating <br/>column
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        This one fill the rest
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
}

#left {
    width:20%;
    background-color: green; 
}

#right {
    width:80%;
    background-color: red; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/KFmVJ/1/

Comment: Hey, this is best solution with out jquery and also being very used full for me please someone who has rights to approve this answer then please approve this. because this is very used full

Answer (score 1):

Jquery solution, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/g4zQR/)

```
$(function() {
  var fHgt = $('#float').outerHeight();

  $('#fill').css({ height: fHgt });
});
```

and here's a CSS solution

```
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#float {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green; 
}
#fill {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'd like to make it using pure css